# Multisort() 3 arrays after usort() one of them

Tags: php, arrays, usort

I'm building an online store for a clothes selling company. When displaying the products on page, the user has to be able to filter the clothes by SIZE. I also show them how many clothes belong to the specific sizes.

For this porpuse I use three arrays: $size_names, $size_ids, $size_counts

The first array can hold numeric and string values together, so it could look like this:

```
array(1, 2, 3, 'M', 'L', 'S')
```

What I basically want is to sort the values within this array in the following logic:

- sort the numerical elements first, ascending
- sort alphabetical elements in the following order: XXS, XS, S, M, L, XL, XXL

I read about usort(), but the problem is that I need to reorder all three arrays (size_names, size_ids, size_counts) by the reordering rule of only size_names.

So I have to sort the first array, than based on the sort, I have to sort the other two.

**EDIT**
One possible scenario with my three arrays could be like:

```
$size_names = array(3, 1, M, S)
$size_ids = array(1, 2, 3, 4)
$size_counts = array(10, 8, 3, 2)
```

So based on the array values I can say to the visitor that there are **TWO** clothes that have size **S**, which size has the id **4**. (The ID value is not shown to the visitor, only helps me building the sql for filtering.)

I currently use array_multisort:

```
array_multisort($size_names, $size_ids, $size_counts);
```

which produces the following result:

```
$size_names = array(1, 3, M, S)
$size_ids = array(2, 1, 3, 4)
$size_counts = array(8, 10, 3, 2)
```

This is half way there, because the numeric values are sorted in the desired order, but the alphabetical values are sorted alphabetically, which is not what I want.

The desired order should be:

```
$size_names = array(1, 3, S, M)
$size_ids = array(2, 1, 4, 3)
$size_counts = array(8, 10, 2, 3)
```

Comment: Why do you even have 3 separate arrays and don't group together what belongs together?

Comment: You should show your arrays code and show what output you expect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the alphabetical elements with numbers, do the sorting and then bring the alphabetical elements back. The following is an example:

```
$size_names = array(3, 1, "M", "S");
$size_ids = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
$size_counts = array(10, 8, 3, 2);

$arr1 = array("XXS", "XS", "S", "M", "L", "XL", "XXL");
$arr2 = range(1001, 1007);

$size_names = str_replace($arr1, $arr2, $size_names);

array_multisort($size_names, $size_ids, $size_counts);

$size_names = str_replace($arr2, $arr1, $size_names);
```

[**DEMO**](https://eval.in/170164)

Comment: Very creative approach! I have to study what other numbers could get in the array, before this action, and choose the temporary numbers accordingly!